# Do we know which mining software Satoshi used?

Tags: mining-hardware

I am trying to figure out why the mining software is not included in the coin wallet you wish to mine and why do we need to find some third party less trustworthy sources to mine

Answer (score 2):

"Bitcoin" currently known as "Bitcoin Core". It used to have a miner, which was removed recently (1-2 years) Of course, he used the software he designed.

Answer (score 0):

you will find all the needed information about the original satoshi client here https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client. unlike the current clients the original one has an internal miner.